# How do you install Khexedit in Ubuntu? I couldnt not find it

Tags: software-installation

Does anyone know how to install khexedit in ubuntu 14.04?

Its in the HARDY manpages here:
http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/hardy/man1/khexedit.1.html

How can i get it in Ubuntu 14.04?

Comment: Have you tried installing from source?

Comment: The source is kde1 and kde2, but kubuntu is now on kde4, so I dont know :(

Comment: I see. I'm really unsure about it. If you want to, try with the steps of my answer. I will make it CW so you can edit with your results.

Comment: Thank you kindly for your CW below. Not working too well unfortunately (neither for the kde1 or kde2 folder), failed at the ./configure Part: checking whether ln -s works... yes
ltconfig: you must specify a host type if you use `--no-verify'
Try `ltconfig --help' for more information.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The package `kdeutils` and all its binaries has been [separated in smaller tar files](https://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi?bug=681386) and the `khexedit` binary was deleted from Debian and Ubuntu repositories. This is since the khexedit binary was [replaced by okteta](http://lists.kde.org/?l=kde-commits&m=132312222010732&w=2). Okteta is available in all the current Ubuntu repositories, and to install it just run:

```
sudo apt-get install okteta
```

Comment: OHHHHHHHH! So Okteta is the new version of khexedit? Thank you so much

Answer (score 2):

Disclaimer: I have no idea if this will work :/

1. Open a terminal <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd>
2. Get the source package with the next command

   `wget http://home.online.no/~espensa/khexedit/khexedit-0.8.5.tar.gz`
3. Unpack tar ball

   `tar xzvf khexedit-0.8.5.tar.gz`
4. Change the directory for install

   `cd khexedit-0.8.5/kde1x`
5. Configure the installation

   `./configure --prefix=/usr/local/kde`
6. Now compile

   `make`
7. And *finally* install

   `sudo make install`

Source: [installation instructions](http://home.online.no/~espensa/khexedit/INSTALL.txt).